# Plugins directory Eclipse Mars.2 OSX EL Capitan

Tags: eclipse, plugins, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to install jadclipse in Eclipse Mars.2 but I could not find the correct plugin directory. The OS OSX EL Capitan.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The plugins directory is inside the Eclipse application.

In Finder right click on the Eclipse app and choose 'Show Package Contents'.

The plugins directory is then in 'Contents > Eclipse > plugins'.

The full path would be '/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins'.

Comment: Thanks gregg for your response

Comment: Hi greg , plugins  does not appear in '/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse' , but I have found 'dropin' directory which seems supporting plugins . Thanks greg